# Multiple Languages in one page

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way with to get multiple languages in one page?
So if I had something like this:

```
<div id="content-English"> Hello, user </div>
<div id="content-Dutch"> Hallo, gebruiker </div>
```

Is it possible to only show the English when I have selected English in my Language Selector and hide the Dutch but when I have selected Dutch display the Dutch and hide the English?
I know this can be done with JavaScript but I don't know how, Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Make each one a class... not an ID, then you can only show all the elements with the language (class) you want

Comment: @ElGuapo I need the javascript, know how the HTML is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to achieve this is shown below, its not nice and a server side solution should be used instead.

Also its better to use Css to hide and how the elements rather than the JavaScript.

Fiddle

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var languageSelector = document.getElementById('languageSelector');

  languageSelector.onchange = function() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="content-"]');

    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      var element = elements[i];
      element.style.display = element.className.indexOf(this.value) < 0 ? 'none' : 'block';
    }
  };
  languageSelector.onchange();
};
```

```html
<select id="languageSelector">
  <option value="content-English">English</option>
  <option value="content-Dutch">Dutch</option>
</select>

<div class="content-English">Hello, user</div>
<div class="content-Dutch">Hallo, gebruiker</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, got an almost similar answer above but that was with jQuery this is plain JS

Answer (score 3):

You can create a CSS class for each language and then show/hide based on the selector's value; something like this:

```
function Start() {

    $('#LanguageSelect').change(function () {

        $('.Language').hide();
        $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
    });

    $('#LanguageSelect').change();    
}

$(Start);
```

HTML:

```
<select id="LanguageSelect">
    <option>English</option>
    <option>French</option>
    <option>German</option>
</select>

<div class="Language English">Hello</div>
<div class="Language French">Bonjour</div>
<div class="Language German">Hallo</div>
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m2rcnepe/3/)

I would recommend a server-side option for a large website but for a light site this option might actually be better.

Comment: This is also jquery... :( the OP specified javascript

Comment: jQuery IS javascript.

Comment: jQuery is a javascript *library* - but it may be that the OP can't use it.

Comment: This is what I meant. Thanks for your answer! I have jQuery linked to my page so thats not a problem at all.

Comment: There is no need for the `.each` function. This could be simplified as in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7566kpa1/2/)

Comment: @Finiox for future reference, it would be much more helpful if you tag your question with all the tags that can apply to avoid confusion

Comment: @Huangism couldn't tag **Language** or **Multiple** cause the tags didn't exist.

Comment: @R.Schifini: yes, it can be simplified, even down to this: https://jsfiddle.net/7566kpa1/4/ and also, show(0) is same as show()

Comment: Very clean code @frenchie.  No, [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) has a default of 400 miliseconds, not 0.

Comment: @R.Schifini: wow, indeed never noticed the default so I continued reading the doc and came to this sentence (top third of page) With no parameters, the .show() method is the simplest way to display an element:

1
$( ".target" ).show();
The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation.

Comment: @Finiox I meant jQuery, if you are willing to accept answers in jquery, you should tag the question with it, this will help you get more attention as well

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery and then do:

```
$("#English-button").click(function(){
    $(".content-English").show(0);
    $(".content-Dutch").hide(0);
    $(".content-German").hide(0);
    $(".content-Spanish").hide(0);
})
```

whenever you click the button for English.
Change the show/hide accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice to use the `class` attribute when it's not unique.

Using pure javascript, you could then get all of the elements with a certain class and hide them:

```js
var langElems = document.getElementsByClassName('lang-fr'), i;

for (var i = 0; i < langElems.length; i ++) {
    langElems[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<p class="lang-fr">Le plus grand faible des hommes, c'est l'amour qu'ils ont de la vie.</p>

<p class="lang-en">Hello world</p>

<p class="lang-fr">Le plus grand faible des hommes, c'est l'amour qu'ils ont de la vie.</p>
```

And, here is a way to toggle showing and hiding the elements using a select option:

```js
// get all elements with the class 'lang;
var langElems = document.getElementsByClassName('lang');


function updateLang() {
    // selection value
    var selectedLang = document.getElementById("select-lang").value;

    // loop through the langauge elements
    for (var i = 0; i < langElems.length; i++) {
        // show those that have the selected val as a class
        if (hasClass(langElems[i], selectedLang)) {
            langElems[i].style.display = 'block';
        } else { // hide those that do not
            langElems[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}

// helper to check if an element contains a class
function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
```

```html
<select id="select-lang" onchange="updateLang()">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="fr">French</option>
</select>
<p class="lang fr">Le plus grand faible des hommes, c'est l'amour qu'ils ont de la vie.</p>
<p class="lang en">Hello world</p>
<p class="lang fr">Le plus grand faible des hommes, c'est l'amour qu'ils ont de la vie.</p>
```

HTH